# Make a plot from a csv file with thousand entries in python

Tags: python, csv, matplotlib, visualize

I have this code in python, which is working.

```
from matplotlib import style
from matplotlib import pylab as plt
import numpy as np

style.use('ggplot')

filename='results.csv'
value=[]
date=[]

import csv
with open(filename, 'r') as csvfile:
    csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in csvreader:
        if len(row) ==2:
            value.append(row[0])
            date.append(row[1])

value=np.array(value)

import datetime
for ii in range(len(date)):
    date[ii]=datetime.datetime.strptime(date[ii], '%a %b %d')
plt.ylim(2, -2) 
plt.plot(date, value)

plt.show()
```

And the .csv file(almost 18000 entries) :

```
[0.0]   Thu Mar 15
[0.0]   Thu Mar 15
[0.0]   Thu Mar 15
[0.0]   Thu Mar 15
[-0.05] Thu Mar 15
[0.0]   Thu Mar 15
[0.0]   Thu Mar 15
    ....
```

So, when I run the code I get this result:[image]

The thing is that I want to have the values in the y axis  from [-2,2] in ascending order so to observe the route of the plotline. Is my rationale for visualizing such a csv wrong or do I have missed something important? I would appreciate any help.

Comment: with ascending order, then the timeseries will not be ordered...?

Comment: I didn't understand. The dates are fine. What I want is the scale on the y-axis to change from [2, -0.05, 0] being now to [-0.05, 0, 2].

Answer (score 0):

Your values have surrounding braces, don't know why. When i try this code with *numpy 1.14.1* and *matplotlib 2.0.0* it throws an exception, that you cannot convert *[0.0]* into float.

After trying this code in Anaconda (*matplotlib 2.1.2* and *numpy 1.14.0*) the code works. However, the y-Scale is displayed wrong. I think there's maybe a bug in one of this packages.

First of all, you should convert your *[0.0]* value with eval (from the ast package) into a list, and then take the first element of the list. So just modify your *value.append*

```
import ast
.
.
value.append(ast.literal_eval(row[0])[0])
```

After that, you set up matplotlib to display from 2 to -2. You should set *ylim* like this:

```
plt.ylim(-0.05, 2)
```

So the full example

```
from matplotlib import style
from matplotlib import pylab as plt
import numpy as np
import ast

style.use('ggplot')

filename='results.csv'
value=[]
date=[]

import csv
with open(filename, 'r') as csvfile:
    csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter='\t')
    for row in csvreader:
        if len(row) ==2:
            value.append(ast.literal_eval(row[0])[0])
            date.append(row[1])

value=np.array(value)

import datetime
for ii in range(len(date)):
    date[ii]=datetime.datetime.strptime(date[ii], '%a %b %d')
plt.ylim(-0.05, 2) 
plt.plot(date, value)
print(value)

plt.show()
```

Moreover, there are much better solutions for your task. Consider to use pandas. I assumed you need year 2018.

```
from matplotlib import style
from matplotlib import pylab as plt
from dateutil.parser import parse
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import ast

style.use('ggplot')

filename = 'results.csv'
df = pd.read_csv('results.csv', sep='\t')
df.columns = ['value', 'date']
# Convert to datetime
df.date = df.date.apply(lambda x:
    parse(x, default=datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 1)))
# Unpack your list elements
df.value = df.value.apply(lambda x: ast.literal_eval(x)[0])

plt.plot(df.date, df.value)
plt.ylim(-0.05, 2)

plt.show()
```

As mentioned in comments, using eval is a security issue. Better use *literal_eval* from the *ast* package.

Comment: You shouldn't use `eval` for such cases - what if a line in that file you read is `import os;os.system('rm -rf /')`?

Answer (score 0):

Using pandas simplifies things a lot. You may directly strip the brackets from the data when reading the file.

```
u = u"""[0.0]\tThu Mar 14
[0.0]\tThu Mar 15
[0.0]\tThu Mar 16
[0.0]\tThu Mar 17
[-0.05]\tThu Mar 18
[2.0]\tThu Mar 19
[0.0]\tThu Mar 20"""

import io
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime

parse_date = lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x, "%a %b %d")
parse_vals = lambda x: float(x.strip("[]"))
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(u), sep="\t",header=None,names=["val", "date"],
                 converters={0:parse_vals,1:parse_date} )

df.set_index("date").plot()

plt.show()
```

[image]